# Single model instances on separate html

Tags: django, django-models

What is a best way to display single model instances on different html? I know how it is done on single page (forloop), but could not figure out how the same would be possible on different html. i.e. single question per page?

my pseudo model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  desc = models.CharField()
```

Comment: Also for loop? It's html. You probably need to rephrase the question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is by using the object `unique identifier` or `pk`. You pass this information to the view using [url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments). Then you would retrieve the single object using its `pk` and send to template e.g. `return render(request, 'single_obj_template.html', {'question': question})`